# Schengen travel insurance for couple

Tags: schengen, insurance, schengen-visas

As per my understanding each individual is required to hold a travel insurance of 30,000 Euro for the process of application for a Schengen visa.

However, The travel insurance that I have purchased is a couple insurance for a total of 50,000 USD (approx 46,000 EUR). When me and my wife applies for a schengen visa, can we both submit the same insurance proof or do I have to buy another separate insurance for my wife ?

The insurance that we have purchased states both of our names on the same page.

Should I apply for a visa directly by taking a chance and in case they find it short, will they straight away reject the visa or allow me to buy another insurance ?

Comment: Does the insurance state both your names on the same page?

Comment: Yes, it states both of our names on the same page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Article 15 of the [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810&from=EN) mentions that:

> The insurance shall be valid throughout the territory of the Member
>   States and cover the entire period of the person’s intended stay or
>   transit. The minimum coverage shall be EUR 30 000.

Presuming your insurance covers two people at once, it should be issued for a sum of more than EUR 60 000. When applying for a visa the consulate will give you a chance to amend your application by providing a different insurance. However if you ignore their recommendation and submit an inadequate piece of insurance, your application will be rejected.

Therefore the answer is: purchase a different insurance or amend your existing policy.

Also note that Schengen consulates only accept policies from [approved insurance companies](http://www.mzv.cz/newdelhi/en/ko/travel_medical_insurance_new_regulation.html), so you need to make sure your insurance company is on that list before applying.

Comment: Or contact the insurer and see whether the coverage can be increased under the same policy (probably with added cost).

Comment: It might be true but I don't see how the €60000 figure follows from the text. Both are covered and both are covered for €30000 (more than that actually). What is not covered is spending €30000 on medical costs *at the same time*, a distinct and even smaller risk. For all I know the consulate might interpret the requirement that way but it's not obvious. So I don't find the answer particularly helpful.

Comment: @Relaxed true; would having a joint policy be a disadvantage?

Comment: @Dorothy I don't know and Jonathan is right that the risk is indeed a refusal so I would not risk it either.

Comment: @Relaxed I agree that the risk is minuscule, but I think the law is pretty clear about the requirements. Of course, the consulate might still accept OP's documents, but I personally wouldn't risk a rejection over it.

Comment: @JonathanReez But that's not what I am saying ;) The risk of a refusal might very well be significant… but the law is *not* clear.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to point out that based on my personal experience, travel insurance is not the same thing as Schengen insurance.

Therefore, it is recommended that **unless your travel insurance provider can give a reference for its insurance for Schengen countries** do not risk rejection, especially as the base coverage of 30,000 EUR can be obtained online for a nominal amount.

I know some people have been rejected because their credit card provides travel insurance (if the tickets are purchased on the card) but this insurance doesn't have the same provisions as Schengen-mandated insurance.

In short, not worth the risk.

Comment: Assuming OP is from India, here is the list of approved insurance companies: http://www.mzv.cz/newdelhi/en/ko/travel_medical_insurance_new_regulation.html